# How to read a custom header value in the AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax

Our application performs CORS compliant Ajax requests. As a side note, for custom headers, we have included the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header in the response.

Now, I'm trying to add a custom header to my ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    headers: {"MyCustomHeader":"true"}
    ...
})
```

I see it in the request and in the response as `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: MyCustomHeader`.

However, I am unable to read the value of the custom header that was sent. When I perform the `getResponseHeader('MyCustomHeader')` call in the Ajax complete delegate, the value turns up empty.

```
$.ajax({
    complete: function(x) {
        console.log(x.getResponseHeader("MyCustomHeader")); //Returns NULL
    }
})
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you add the code in the description for understanding the issue a bit more clear Please :)

Comment: sorry for the silly question, is the `MyCustomHeader` actually in the ajax response or is it in `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`? could you double check with browser console network tab?

Comment: @BagusTesa, it is in the response headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because even though I included the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header with the custom header key, I didn't actually include the `MyCustomHeader` header in the response.

So doing `HttpResponse.AppendHeader('MyCustomHeader')` server-side solved the problem.